# how to append a row/line to a multi row/line dictionary

Tags: python

so i have this pymysql dictionary. basically an entire table.
with many rows.

thanks to:

```
conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

when i print one row/line it looks like this

```
{u'key1': 10, u'key2': 20}
```

so i assume the entire dictionary looks like this:

```
{{u'key1': 10, u'key2': 20},
{u'key1': 11, u'key2': 21},
{u'key1': 12, u'key2': 22}}
```

**how can i append a row/line??**

```
dict.append({u'key1': 13, u'key2': 23})
```

*also..
why cant i use dict[0] to access a row of the dictionary?
i have to use a for loop just to get 1 row?*

Comment: What you're showing there is a `list` of `dict`s. You can `append()` to a `list`, but not to a `dict`. Please show the whole code and the error you get.

Comment: You should probably first put a LIMIT into your query to select a number of rows and look at the actual structure returned. The structure you're imagining is not a dictionary, but a list containing dictionaries.

Comment: i cant print the entire dictionary. when i try it prints "<pymysql.cursors.DictCursor object at 0x11a164890>"
and when i try append it throws attributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Then you're trying to print the cursor object. First remember to LIMIT your query so you only get a reasonable/manageable number of results and then `print(cursor.fetchall())`

Comment: Can you show a full code!? Is not clear!

Comment: @roganjosh wow. okey that solved the problem. i was not actually handling a dict but a cursor.
now it behaves like expected. dict[0] works and dict.append works as well
thanks

Comment: now what do we do with this question? should i delete it ? or answer it?
i think this might happen to someone in the future as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually shown the code for retrieving your query results but we can see in the comments that you're trying to print the `cursor` object. I suspect that in your code you were iterating through the `cursor` object to retrieve values one-by-one.This is supported, but different than if you want all your results in one go (you just get single dictionaries for each line, which won't support `.append()` or indexing).

Instead, use `cursor.fetchall()` to get the structure you imagined you had. Note that it is actually a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.